# How to link RCpp with ALGLIB library?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, alglib

I am trying to use Rcpp package and ALGLIB library together to use the kd tree functions of the ALGLIB. What can I do to link the ALGLIB with Rcpp? My src folder is as such

```
src/
  |- Makevars
  |- Makevars.win
  |- alglibmisc.h
  |- alglibmisc.cpp
  |- alglibinternal.cpp
  |- alglibinternal.h
  |- ap.cpp
  |- ap.h
```

My beginning of the code looks like

```
#include <RcppEigen.h> 
#include "alglibmisc.h"
```

I get the error:  Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("src/rcppeigen_hello_world.cpp") :
Error occurred building shared library when trying to compile the code.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please have a look around at resources such as [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as it is currently rather difficult to say anything here. The recently released Rcpp 1.0.5 also contains a new (tenth) vignette about [building a package with an external library](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-libraries.pdf) which is the same as [this arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06416).

Comment: You wrote you used `sourceCpp()`. That is _not_ used to build a package, and will _e.g._ ignore the `src/Makevars` you have.  Package building is done with `R CMD build` or wrappers around it.